# Where is sbt inside Typesafe Activator?

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am trying out the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) 2.3.2 using the offline installation with [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) 1.2.3. Every piece of documentation tells me that it's using sbt under the covers to build and run projects.

Where is this sbt located/installed? Is it somewhere in the unzipped folder that contained the Activator installation?

How do I start sbt from command line? It's not on the `PATH` as running `locate sbt` finds nothing.

Comment: The activator jar contains sbt, as activator is wrapping it. It doesn't install sbt on your system.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke it without running Activator?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `activator-launcher-<version>.jar` is actually the sbt launcher with an additional properties file embedded.

If you run `activator shell` (or any other command you may have used with sbt like `compile` or `package`) you're starting sbt itself that in turn executes the commands.

Here's the path of applications that get launched:

1. `activator ui` launches the activator UI which launches a sub-sbt process to build
2. `activator new` launches the activator template creation terminal application.
3. `activator shell` or `activator <sbt input>` launches sbt itself.

In addition, the `activator` script attempts to detect if it's run from a "UI" context, e.g. double-clicking from Windows Explorer or OSX Finder. If so, the script will automatically start in UI mode.

Comment: Each of the activator commands that you have mentioned seems to trigger a chain of never ending downloads. Is this normal ?

Comment: It is normal if the version you downlaoded is out of date. It should not happen every time you start up.