# Activator vs sbt

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I upgraded from Play 2.1.1 to Play 2.3.2.

Now Typesafe has "Activator", which combines the several offerings of their platform.

I installed the "minimal" form of it, which is supposed to download features only as needed.

Then I thought, "Hey, isn't that the point of a build and dependency management tools like, I don't know, SBT?"

I found that I could just go to my Play project and run

`sbt`

Does this do something significantly different than running

`activator`

---

(If I could just use SBT, I'd prefer that, since it has a Debian package, which IMO is easier to manage.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is sbt inside Typesafe Activator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084045/where-is-sbt-inside-typesafe-activator)

Answer (score 3):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084045/where-is-sbt-inside-typesafe-activator) -- the activator-launch.jar file is the sbt launcher with an embedded properties file.