# Difference between "play compile" and "sbt compile"

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.2

Is there any difference between "play compile" and "sbt compile"? When I compile my application using "play compile" it compiles fine but when I do the same with "sbt compile" I get the error

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.abc.xyz#xyz-lib;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

However this dependency is available in my local maven repository (`$HOME/.m2/repository`).

Can you please help me understand why the compilation fails when I use `sbt` specifically and what is the difference between `sbt` and `play` compilation?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101066/activator-vs-sbt) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084045/where-is-sbt-inside-typesafe-activator)

Comment: Besides that, play framework also customizes class loader to enable `hit refresh workflow`.

Comment: I'm using Play 2.2.0. This version of Play also has Activator?

Comment: `activator` is similar to `play` in regards of your question, because it is again a script.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `play` command, you are invoking either `play` shell script or `play.bat` batch script. This will also pull in some configuration from your play setup:

Perhaps `play` command is pulling in a repository configuration. This is what I get:

```
play-2.2.3/framework/project/

find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e resolver {} +
./Build.scala:49:    resolvers ++= typesafeResolvers,
./Build.scala:291:      resolvers += typesafeIvyReleases,
./RepositoryBuilder.scala:38:    resolvers <+= localRepo apply { f => Resolver.file(localRepoName, f)(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) },
./RepositoryBuilder.scala:68:      log.debug("Module: " + mrid + " should use resolver: " + name)
```

However when you use `sbt`, you are essentially dependent on the project confguration you have setup for your application.

I think there is where your answer lies.